# Javascript inheritance & Apply

Tags: javascript

I have been looking into design patterns in Javascript and found http://tcorral.github.com/Design-Patterns-in-Javascript/Template/withoutHook/index.html to be a great source.

Can anyonne explain the significance of using ***ParentClass.apply(this)***

```
var CaffeineBeverage = function(){

};
var Coffee = function(){
    CaffeineBeverage.apply(this);
};
Coffee.prototype = new CaffeineBeverage();
```

PS: I tried commenting the CaffeineBeverage.apply(this), but no effect was there. Here is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pramodpv/8XqW9/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It simply applies the parent constructor to the object being constructed. Try adding some stuff to the `CaffeineBeverage` constructor and you'll see what I mean.

```
var CaffeineBeverage = function(){
    this.tweakage = '123';
};

var Coffee = function(){
    CaffeineBeverage.apply(this);
};
```

Don't do this: `Coffee.prototype = new CaffeineBeverage()`. Do this instead:

```
Coffee.prototype = Object.create(CaffeineBeverage.prototype);
```

For more information on that, see [this article](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), which also provides a shim for older browsers, which don't have `Object.create`.

Testing it out:

```
var drink = new Coffee();
console.log(drink.tweakage); // 123
```

Comment: wow!! that is great. on a side note.. why do you go for Object.create(CaffeineBeverage.prototype) instead of .prototype = new CaffeineBeverage()

Comment: doing `Object.create` is actually slower than prototype dance. http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-crockford-vs-jorge-vs-constructor/27 One should use some kind of CoffeeScript `__extend` functionality or direct dance with prototype + helper function in order to inherit shared properties, performance wise.

Comment: @gryzzly very interesting, I've never checked. I personally always do the prototype dance; I'm just oldschool like that. I wonder why this is though.

Comment: @PramodSyneITY because generally don't want to invoke the constructor in order to get a copy of its prototype. In some cases you won't be able to. What if the constructor has mandatory arguments?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of looking at that example, let's flesh out our own:

```
var Room = function()
{
  this.doors = 1;
};
```

Much like `call`, `apply` will execute the function, but allow you to specify what `this` is. In the example above, I'm specifying `this.doors = 1`, which makes `doors` a member when we've created our instance of `Room`.

Now, if I do this:

```
var ComputerRoom = function() 
{
  Room.apply(this);
  // I can now access the this.doors member:

  this.doors = this.doors + 1;
};
```

I'm actually saying that `this` in the context of the `Room` constructor, is actually the instance of `ComputerRoom`, which is why I pass it into the `apply` command: `Room.apply(this)`.

Comment: wow!! i have been reading for hours but nothing has been getting into my brain. Thanks for the simple answer... However i can't mark this as answer since @GGG beat it in 2 mins!!

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are calling apply in the sub-"class" constructor is to inherit all instance properties.

Here's  an example:

```
var CaffeineBeverage = function (caffeine) {
    this.caffeineContent = caffeine || "100"; // 100mg / cup is an average
};

var Espresso = function (caffeine) {
    // inherit instance properties
    CaffeineBeverage.apply( this, arguments );
};

// do prototype dance to inherit shared properties
var protoCarrier = function () {};
protoCarrier.prototype = CaffeineBeverage.prototype;
Espresso.prototype = new protoCarrier;

var espressoCup = new Espresso(50); 
espressoCup.caffeineContent; // 50
```

This is why you call `apply`. Also, `apply` allows you to send the arguments (with our example of `caffeine`). Arguments are put in array-like object in JavaScript, and `apply` accepts an array to pass arguments to the function that is being invoked. This explains why to use `apply` over `call` in this case (otherwise, `call` is faster and should be used when your code doesn't require array of arguments).

Comment: Interesting. But how does it know that there is a `caffeine` argument in the `arguments`? `arguments` is an array, right, `[50]`? It is not a an object `{caffeine: 60}`. So, how does it possible `this.caffeineContent = caffeine || "100";`? There is no `caffeine` variable, there is only `arguments[0]`

Comment: @Green that is how `apply` method works. It will: receive an array of values as an argument and use these values as arguments on the function that `apply` is being called on. It’s practically the same as doing `new CaffeineBeverage(arguments[0])`, while also binding the execution context of the constructor to `this` which is the first argument of the `apply` method.

Comment: that is also simply how function arguments work – in the calling scope you have variables that you can use to invoke functions with named arguments: `var args = [1, 2]; function add(a, b) { return a + b } add(args[0], args[1]);` – we are referring to values as items of an array, but inside the function body the arguments are available as named variables.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

Apply `calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array.`

In your example you will be calling the CaffeineBeverage function, but when `this` is referenced within that function it will be the same Object as the `this` which is passed to it.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)